# Eukaryotic cell lysate-based protein expression efficiency

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, proteins, protein-expression

What is average efficiency of eukaryotic cell lysate-based protein expression systems in terms of (mg of protein expressed) / (mg of lysate) ?

Comment: This is nothing what you can determine that easy. The question is from what cells your lysate is prepared, how does your protein sequence look like (long or short and so on) and other parameters. You can have a look into commercial kits, which may give you a yield estimate, but this might not be true. Also: Functional protein or just total protein?

Comment: Total protein .